# Можно ли в Git (через PHPStorm) вывести дерево ВСЕХ коммитов и веток?

Tags: git, phpstorm, дерево

Например, как в проводнике Windows выводится структура корневого каталога - там можно сделать так, что будут видны все вложенные каталоги и файлы.

И - как сюда скриншот вставить? Я недавно на этом форуме, что-то не пойму.

Comment: git log --all --decorate ?

Comment: Не совсем. Это - консоль, а я быхотел визуально, как на картинке ниже. Но, почему-то у меня нет панели №1

Answer (score 2):

Видимо это то, что Вы ищете https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/log-tab.html

[image]

Открывается по "View | Tool Windows | Version Control | Log" или <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.

Comment: Спасибо... но у меня почему-то нет  Branches pane (обозначенной цифрой 1). Есть только панели 2,3,4.

Comment: Как сюда скриншот (пример)  вставить?

Comment: там в верхнем левом угле видно угловую скобочку. Если на неё нажать, то панель появится.

Comment: Там нет у меня такой скобки.